# Comparing coordinates of two array indexes

Tags: c++, arrays

I am creating a basic C++ game which involves a user trying to escape from zombies.

The zombies are stored in an array called `zeds`. There are traps laid out throughout the game which are supposed to reset the zombies to their initial position, stored in an array named `holes`.

I am trying to figure out how I can compare the coordinates of the zombies with the coordinates of the holes, and if they match, reset the zombies.

I don't know how I'd begin with comparing the coordinates of the zeds with the coordinates of the holes. I have tried writing this, but it doesn't work.

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAXZEDS; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; i < MAXHOLES; ++j)
    {
        if (zeds[i].x == holes[j].x && zeds[i].y == holes[j].y)
        {
                //reset cords code here
        }
    }
}
```

Appreciate any help,

Thanks guys!

Comment: If your coordinates are `int`s, this should work. What does it do ?

Comment: `i < MAXHOLES` should be `j < MAXHOLES` ?

Comment: This solution is quite inefficient if you plan to spawn more zombies. Perhaps you should think about terrain division into smaller grids to improve "collision" detection?

Comment: @Thronghar oh. It's a typo question then...

Comment: Absolutely right Thronghar, can't believe I missed that! Thanks so much guys.

Answer (score 1):

you have several typos in your code , where i supposed to be j in the thirs line. anyway, you can inhence the readabilty of your code by using OOP practices. 
let's say you have a Point class that holds x and y (which I suppose you have)

```
srtuct Point{
   int x,y;
};
```

first lets overload the `==` operator in order to comapare points

```
srtuct Point{
   int x,y;
   bool operator == (const Point& rhs){
     return x==rhs.x && y == rhs.y;
   }
};
```

now lets use range-semantics instead of indexes and another c++11 features

```
for (auto& zombieCoord : zeds){
   for (auto& holeCoord : holes){
     if (zombieCoord  == holeCoord ){
        //do somthing
     }
   }
}
```

isn't it smaller, cleaner and more clear ?
another things you might want : 
I continued with using x and y as public members like you did, but I suggest making them private and make getters (and if needed) setters.
you might also want to call them in some convention, like m_X and m_Y, which signifies them as **m**embers. 
also, another developer may not understand what `zeds` may mean. why not give it a clear name like "ongoingZombies"?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your loop is wrong. The second Loop has to check j

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the second `for`, you where checking `i` instead of `j`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAXZEDS; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < MAXHOLES; ++j)
    {
        if (zeds[i].x == holes[j].x && zeds[i].y == holes[j].y)
        {
                //reset cords code here
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how your zombies move but it might be difficult for a zombie's coordinates to match exactly the coordinates of a hole. What I mean is that it might be unlikely for a zombie to fall into a hole. Maybe you should try to consider also their size, like the hole and the zombie have squares shapes and when the zombie's square touches the holes it falls into. Have a look at [how to detect collisions between squares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157785/i-have-two-squares-drawn-on-the-screen-how-can-i-detect-collision-on-the-edges)

This code does `MAXZEDS * MAXHOLES` iterations, which might be a lot. You might also want to implement a more efficient way of collision detection. Have a look at [Quadtrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), I bet there is somewhere a good C++ implementation. They are simple and very efficient.