# Java - Check if 4 points (forming a rectangle) "collides" with another 4 points

Tags: java, math

I am creating a Roguelike dungeon generator, and part of this involves checking if a room (which is represented by x1, y1, x2, y2) "collides" with another room. If this is the case, the room will be regenerated. I've tried Googling a bit, but I've yet to find anything that works. Here is some code based off of what I found online, but it always seems to return true.

```
public static boolean isInside(int minX1, int minY1, int maxX1, int maxY1, int minX2, int minY2, int maxX2, int maxY2) {
    if(Math.abs(minX1 - minX2) < (minX1 + maxX1) + (minX2 + maxX2)) {
        if(Math.abs(minY1 - minY2) < (minY1 + maxY1) + (minY2 + maxY2)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Are the rooms square on the xy grid?

Comment: @TungstenX The rooms are rectangular

Comment: My apology, what I meant was, does the room walls follow the xy grid, e.g [ ] or can they be diagonal \ \?

Comment: @TungstenX Ah,  all the rooms follow the x, y grid.  There's no diagonals :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157785/i-have-two-squares-drawn-on-the-screen-how-can-i-detect-collision-on-the-edges

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `intersects()` method in the `Rectangle` class:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#intersects-java.awt.Rectangle-

Answer (score 0):

I check if apex of the rectangle is inside of another rectangle.

```
if ((minX1 <= minX2 <= maxX1 || minX1 <= maxX2 <= maxX1 ) && (minY1 <= minY2 <= maxY1 || minY1 <= maxY2 <= maxY1))
return true;
```